# React/Redux How to get map function values into a custom function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am doing a recent searches functionality by fetching an array from redux store and mapping through it get the values out of it.

```
            <ul className="sidebar__list">
              {searches.map((search, i) => {
                return (
                  <li className="sidebar__listItem" key={i}>
                    <Link
                      to="/venues"
                      onClick={this.onClickRecentSearches(search.query, search.location)}
                      className="sidebar__listItemLink"
                    >
                      {search.query} in {search.location}
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
```

What I want to do is dispatch a action on click. I have a fetchVenues action in reduce which require two inputs. How can i target the values of array and parse it into my action

```
onClickRecentSearches = (place, location) => {
  this.props.fetchVenues(place, location);
};
```

e.target only works for input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make it an anonymous function:

```
onClick={() => this.onClickRecentSearches(search.query, search.location)}
```

Comment: I am receiving this error... "Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`."

Comment: This answer shouldn't cause anything during a render or constructor; it is just calling your `onClickRecentSearches` function when you click a Link

Comment: Is there any better approach to my problem.... I need to feed those search.query and search.location to fetchVenues action.Is there any better way?

Comment: I think this might be another problem with your app

Comment: Well I am printing the search array but when i try to do onCLick Its giving me errors

Comment: Can you show updated code? maybe even a codesandbox?

Comment: here is the sandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/github/montygoldy/hipolabs  Component is in the widget/sidebar/rendersidebar

Comment: if you just try to go to the /venues route, you get that error; something on that component is not what it is supposed to be

Comment: tony I have updated the keys and removed the code I was testing on